# Cant see the actual value of pointer

Tags: c, gdb

I am trying to debug something and using gdb for it.

Basically the code is:

```
css_cmd_t *cmd_sa;
cmd_sa = calloc(...);
```

Now in gdb, I am just after the above code is executed.

```
(gdb) print cmd_sa
$11 = (css_cmd_t *) 0xffffffffe61135f0
(gdb) print *cmd_sa
Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffe61135f0
```

Does anyone know how can I access the contents?

Comment: Can we see the actual code? Your example should work if everything is defined properly and the pointer is actually a valid pointer. Similarly, it could also help to have the gdb execution trace to ensure things like 'did you break after the call to calloc'.

Answer (score 1):

> Now in gdb, I am just after the above code is executed.

I don't believe you.

The value of `cmd_sa` is consistent with it being *declared*, but not yet assigned, and you are probably stopped *before* the actual `calloc` line.

You can verify this with `disas` command, which should show that `CALL calloc` is still to be run.

If GDB tells you that you are stopped *after* the `calloc` line, you might be debugging optimized code, in which case source code to assembly mapping can not be fully trusted. Try executing `next` a few more times, and see if the value of `cmd_sa` changes.

Comment: I would also bet that `s` then `p cmd_sa` makes it look more sensible. `call sizeof(cmd_sa)` may not even be 64-bits!